# Copy Excel data to a formatted Word table via VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

H ey everyone,

I am currently trying to figure out how to fill a table in a MS Word template document with a variable number of data sets from Excel.

The aim is to automatically create a changelog, with all the information coming from tickets within our Jira ticket system.

I chose the Excel -> Word approach, because I have already implemented an Excel application that utilizes the Jira REST-API to retrieve all needed information.

Now only the copying of the data remains and that's where I am stuck.

I already figured out a way to open an existing Word document via

```
Dim word As Word.Application
word.Documents.Open Filename:="""C:\test.doc"""
```

However, I currently have no clue on how to access a specific element within this Word document.

What I would need is a function to name certain elements (like Excel where you can name your Cells/Ranges, just for a Word table), so that I can access them via VBA and paste my data in.

Another problem might be the columns. Can they be accessed specifically?

I never worked with Word VBA before, so I would appreciate any help you guys can provide :)

best regards

daZza

Comment: There is a macro recorder in Word Application. Run it to get code you need for further changes. It is a good starting point, next, come back here with specific questions showing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good overview of the [MS Word Document Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we.aspx) from MSDN. This [section on working with text in the document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386277.aspx) is probably what you're looking for. This will let you define and select ranges of text either from the document or by paragraph. There is also a table object that can be created and used in Word that would let you use cell-specific (row and column) references. It's really not that different than Excel, except that everything is a range of characters within some element (i.e. paragraph) rather than a range of cells. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the references. I had a quick look through them (will evaluate furhter), but it seems that my main problem - the selection of a specific table - is not solved with these ranges. The word ranges seem to be defined by the specific location of something. However, the table I want to insert my data to is not always at the same position and may even contain some entries under certain circumstances. So I can't just define a range on that. I'd need an equivalent to the naming of certain ranges in Excel to access the table whereever it may be located.

Comment: Sorry -- I may have misunderstood. Is it a table in the Word document?  As I said above, there is a Table Object in Word ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834860(v=office.15).aspx ), but I do not believe it has a name property, like Excel would, it'd need to be by index, i.e. ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1,1)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'll gotta find out how Word indexes then, would be great if it's done chronologically, as the table I need to access is always the first one in the whole document, regardless of how many others there are.

Comment: I believe it's at the creation time of the table, rather than where the table appears within the document; there is an ID property, also, but I can't see how to set it. You could create a phantom header cell on the table and search by that, or bookmark the table range and look that way. Here is an example (kinda hacky; mocked it up while on a plane and my laptop is dying :P ): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6KI_P5cLHa2RVJhUVRHN1hETVk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @daZza From the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.interop.word.tables.aspx), the index number represents the position of the table in the document, rather than the date/time created.

Comment: @daZza The equivalent to an Excel named range would be a Bookmark (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837530.aspx).